# How do you put tabs under another layout similar to the Google+ app? (Example Pic Incuded)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-tabhost

I want to implement something simlar to this Google+ layout. The page scrolls until the tabs at the bottom hit the top. Then the list view in the tabs scroll. Does anyone have an idea to do that? (The tabs should still be visible but the content inside scrolls.)

Please don't hesitate to ask for clarification.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to examine that app, I suspect that you will find that the tabs are a tabbed indicator for a `ViewPager`. `PagerTabStrip` is one that ships with the Android Support package, the ViewPagerIndicator library has another, and there are still more floating around out there. Such a tab strip can be placed pretty much anywhere.

Comment: looks like you are right, do you know if it will automatically take care of the scrolling? or would I need scrollview to implement it somehow?

Comment: @Sree: If you mean vertical scrolling, you would need to use a `ScrollView` or something. Tabbed indicators, and `ViewPager` itself, offer horizontal swiping for their contents.

Comment: Yea, but won't it cause issues because you are not supposed to put a listview inside a scrollview? or am i not thinking about this in the right way?

Comment: @Sree: I do not see a `ListView` in your screenshot.

Comment: sorry, it's under the tab, you can barely see it. but if you have the google+ app, you can see what I mean. The user can scroll, once the tab bar hits the top, the list view underneath it will scroll. I guess it may not be a list view but it acts like one.

Comment: @Sree: Use **`uiuautomatorviewer`** and see what they use.